# Pop up of Microsoft Outlook Calendar reminder on all screens / desktops possible?

Tags: ms-office

I use Microsoft Outlook at work.

I happen to miss appointments/meetings because I do not notice the reminder of the event. Later I notice that the reminder popped up in a different screen on the main desktop.

Is there a way to make the reminder more prominent on Mac for Microsoft Outlook ?

Ideally I would like to see the reminder on all three screens no matter whether the desktop is shown or another virtual desktop.

Comment: Are you asking about Outlook and the macOS Spaces feature? This is exactly how Outlook works for me. I have seven separate Spaces and, when an Outlook meeting reminder pops up, it shows up on each of the Spaces. I'm running the very latest versions of both macOS Mojave and Outlook w/Office 365.

Comment: I am not really sure about the terminology to be honest. But I believe what you describe is exactly what I am looking for. I want the reminder to pop up on all visible screens/desktops. Would you please be so kind and let me know how you achieved this? I am unable to find a solution unfortunately.

Comment: Is there really no one who can help with my problem ? I cannot find a solution.

Comment: IIRC, I didn't explicitly do anything to get Outlook to behave as I've described. "It just works." Not helpful, I know. One thing I will mention is that I have the macOS Mission Control preferences in the System Preferences set to *not* give displays separate Spaces. This may be involved somehow; it might be worth a try on your end to uncheck that Mission Control checkbox and see whether it makes a difference.

Comment: I've noticed a bit more nuance: Outlook pop ups show on all my virtual desktops that _don't_  contain fullscreen/split-screen apps. The virtual desktops that have a fullscreen/split-screen app(s) don't show the Outlook pop up notifications.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by adding my Microsoft Outlook calendar account to the Calendar app that came with the MacBook. There, you have more control and by displaying the calendar notifications as Alerts, it always sticks on the top right corner of the screen unless you close it. You can also separate your work and default calendars if you don't feel like combining the two.